# How to use the domino view entries tree node in the extension library outline

Tags: xpages

I've set `var = ViewEntries2 viewName = ApplicationProfiles`

If my first column's name `= Xpage` I've tried setting `labelcolumn = myview.Xpage` and I get an error.  If I use `labelColumn="1"` I get empty nodes.  I can't seem to find much documentation.

```
<xe:basicContainerNode
label="Créer nouvelle requête">
 <xe:this.children>
 <xe:dominoViewEntriesTreeNode
 var="ViewEntries2" viewName="ApplicationProfiles" labelColumn="1" loaded="true" 
  rendered="true">
 </xe:dominoViewEntriesTreeNode>
</xe:this.children></xe:basicContainerNode>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting labelColumn to the programmatic name of the view column (which can be a number such as $1 or can be a name - check the advanced tab of the view column properties).